# Install TensorFlow on R

Tags: r, tensorflow, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

Trying to install TensorFlow via [install_tensorflow](https://github.com/cran/tensorflow/blob/master/R/install.R#L35) in Google Cloud AI Platform notebooks using R kernel:

```
platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu         
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          6.1                         
year           2019                        
month          07                          
day            05                          
svn rev        76782                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
nickname       Action of the Toes
```

I run:

```
install.packages(c("tfestimators", "tfdatasets", "cloudml", "rjson"))
library(tfestimators) # used for creating tensorflow estimators
library(tfdatasets) # used for creating data input functions
library(cloudml) # used for training and deploying models to AI Platform
install_tensorflow()
```

I get:

```
Error in virtualenv_install(envname, packages, ...): unused arguments (python_version = conda_python_version, pip = TRUE)Traceback:1. install_tensorflow()2. reticulate::py_install(packages = c(package, extra_packages), . envname = envname, method = method, conda = conda, python_version = conda_python_version, . pip = TRUE, ...)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the same error trying to install Keras for R. Updating to the latest reticulate version from CRAN and the latest tensorflow version from Github solved the problem:

```
install.packages("reticulate")
devtools::install_github("rstudio/tensorflow")
```

and then

```
library(tensorflow)
install_tensorflow()
```

I used conda instead of venvs.

Comment: Thanks for replying I still got the same error, I'm using a Jupyter Notebook with R kernel, how can I define the conda or venev environment?

Comment: `method` argument in `install_tensorflow` let choose the installation method: https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/tensorflow/articles/installation.html#installation-methods

Comment: install.packages(c("tfestimators", "tfdatasets", "cloudml", "rjson", "reticulate")) did the trick.

Comment: I had the same problems and it helped to install reticulate, tensorflow and keras from github:
`devtools::install_github("rstudio/reticulate")
devtools::install_github("rstudio/tensorflow")
devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras")`